# error that "return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" during making model

Tags: swift, parse-platform, model

I am implementing model with parse.

here is my code.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Parse

class User {

var objectId : String
var username : String
var nickName : String

var phoneNumber : String
var preferPhoneNumber : String
var emailAddress : String
var preferemailAddress : String

var emailVerified : Bool

var createdAt : NSDate
var updatedAt : NSDate

var profile_picture : UIImage

init(objectId:String, username:String, nickName:String, phoneNumber: String, preferPhoneNumber : String, emailAddress : String, preferemailAddress : String, emailVerified : Bool){


self.objectId = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId)!
self.username = (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!

    if var nickName = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("nickName") as? String){
    (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("nickName") as? String)
}else{
    "!NoData"
}

    if var phoneNumber = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("phoneNumber") as? String){
    self.phoneNumber = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("phoneNumber") as? String)!
}else{
    "!NoData"
}

    if var preferPhoneNumber = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("preferPhoneNumber") as? String){
   self.preferPhoneNumber =  (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("preferPhoneNumber") as? String)!
}else{
    "!NoData"
}

    if var emailAddress = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("emailAddress") as? String){
    self.emailAddress = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("emailAddress") as? String)!
}else{
    "!NoData"
}

    if var preferemailAddress = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("preferemailAddress") as? String){
    self.preferemailAddress = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("preferemailAddress") as? String)!
}else{
    "!NoData"
}


    if var emailVerified = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("emailVerified") as? Bool){
    self.emailVerified = (PFUser.currentUser()?.objectForKey("emailVerified") as? Bool)!
}else{
    "!NoData"
}

}
```

}

in my code, I get an error that "return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" during making model.

I tried put "return nil" at the end, it wasn't the solution.

So I am  wondering how I can initialising stored properties?

or how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your stored properties need to have a value after the initializer completes. After taking a quick look I found at least 3 variables you do not assign any value to:

```
var createdAt : NSDate
var updatedAt : NSDate
var profile_picture : UIImage
```

Additionally I think that your if-branches will conflict with that concept as well since in the else case you once again miss out on assigning a value.

Either come up with default or real values of all those fields or change them to be Optionals, like `NSDate?` or `NSDate!`, `String?` or `String!`, etc.

Comment: I deleted those three values, still i am getting same error.

Comment: @JanghyupLee Please read my entire answer, you have to change ALL stored property types OR assign a value to all of them in every case